# is there a way to modify request parameters in webapp2

Tags: python, webapp2

I have a `webapp2` logout request handler like:

```
class EditorLogoutHandler(base.LogoutPage):
    def get(self):
        self.request.get('return_url')
```

I want to change the 'return_url' and call the inherited method in `base.LogoutPage`.

Is there a way to do it? I looked through the docs but can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request attribute which is an instance of [`webapp2.Request`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/webapp2/blob/2.5.2/webapp2.py#L114) subclasses `webob.Request`.

This may not be a precise answer but [`webapp2.Request.get`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/webapp2/blob/2.5.2/webapp2.py#L158) in turn calls [`webapp2.Request.get_all`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/webapp2/blob/2.5.2/webapp2.py#L191) which checks the POST and GET params sent in the request.

If updating `return_url` sent as a parameter in a `HTTP GET` request, you can write:

```
class EditorLogoutHandler(base.LogoutPage):
    def get(self):
        self.request.GET.update({'return_url': 'my-shiny-new-url'})
        super(EditorLogoutHandler, self).get()
```